# how to send mail using javascript?

Tags: javascript, email

I need to send a mail using javascript but i was unable to do it with 
can any one please help with the code.

`var link == "mailto:test@test.com"
             + "&subject=" + escape(":Feedback");
                     window.location.h ref = link;`

Comment: Beginner's question, granted. But why down vote?

Comment: no sure why the down votes but FYI, it doesn't hurt to validate your code before asking a question. For JS you can use http://www.jshint.com/

Answer (score 3):

Your [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) is not valid. You have a space in `href` and `var link ==` should be `var link =`

This works.

```
var link = "mailto:RAS.AMB@Wilhelmsen.com&subject=" + escape(":Feedback");
window.location.href = link;
```

Comment: BTW: You don't need to concatenate with "+".

Comment: Thanks a lot Blowsie the code works fine the above code. the space in href came while pasting code in Stack overflow the main issue was with ==.

Answer (score 3):

You assign `link` variable with `==` which is not correct. Try with:

```
var link = "mailto:RAS.AMB@Wilhelmsen.com&subject=" + escape(":Feedback");
window.location.href = link;
```